# How should I write this SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(tab1.amount) amount
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2
  ON tab1.lp_id = tab2.id
JOIN tab3
  ON tab3.employee_id = tab2.employee_id
WHERE tab1.officeid =123
  AND tab3.space <> 2
```

This works fine.
  Now I want to add some more filter to it. Basically I have a table tab4, in which I have columns employee_id, effective_date, salary. ie for each employee we maintain the dates when the salary got changed (ie multiple records per employee). I want to pick only those employees whose latest salary is greater than 10000. How should I write this?
 Basically I want something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(tab1.amount) amount
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2
   ON tab1.lp_id = tab2.id
JOIN tab3
   ON tab3.employee_id            = tab2.employee_id
WHERE tab1.officeid     =123
   AND tab3.space <> 2
   AND (
        select salary 
        from (
              select * 
              from tab4 
              where  tab4.employee_id  = tab2.employee_id
              order by effective_d desc
              )  
        where rownum = 1
        ) > 10000
```

I am trying to add the last two lines - but I get an error because I cannot use `tab2.employee_id`.

How should I write this?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT      t.employee_id, t.salary
FROM        tab4 t
INNER JOIN  (SELECT     employee_id, MAX(effective_date) as eff_date
            FROM        tab4
            GROUP BY    employee_id) x
            ON t.employee_id = x.employee_id AND t.effective_date = x.eff_date
WHERE       t.salary > 10000
```

This will get you employee with salary greater than 10000

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `INTERSECT` Operator.?

```
SELECT SUM(tab1.amount) amount
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2
   ON tab1.lp_id = tab2.id
JOIN tab3
   ON tab3.employee_id            = tab2.employee_id
WHERE tab1.officeid     =123
   AND tab3.space <> 2
INTERSECT(
        select salary 
        from (
              select * 
              from tab4, tab2
              where  tab4.employee_id  = tab2.employee_id
              order by effective_d desc
              )  
        where rownum = 1
        ) > 10000
```

Comment: It will still doesn't work because tab2 is declared outside of the inner query. you have to use it in the inner query.

Comment: Yeah thats true.! How about declaring it inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT SUM(tab1.amount) amount
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2
ON tab1.lp_id = tab2.id
JOIN tab3
ON tab3.employee_id = tab2.employee_id
WHERE tab1.officeid     =123
AND tab3.space <> 2
AND (
     select salary 
     from (
          select * 
          from tab4 join tab2
          on tab4.employee_id  = tab2.employee_id
          order by effective_d desc
          )  
    where rownum = 1
    ) > 10000
```

Hope this can help you.